# Interface is changing between IOS deployment target version on all buttons

Tags: swift, xcode

I want to give the possibility to use my app since version 14.5. I tested it on version 15.3 and when I changed the iOS deployment target version to 14.5 I have the interface of all my buttons which are changing with the Button title appearing is it a bug, any clue?

I positioned a button with an image on top of the button. The button title is cleared and I am not changing any UIButton title or settings in my code, below the interface with version 15.3 and then the changes with 14.5
Why is it not consistent between versions?

[image: interface with version 15.3]

[image: with version 14.5]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the interface builder, set button style from `plain` to `default`.

[image]